# Symfony POST Value Id transform to entity

Tags: php, symfony

it's newby question but i don't found answer on web :'(

I have Ajax script send Id of Product & Id of Recommendation with POST method

```
$(".isProduct").click(function (e) {
            let productId = $(this).attr('product_id')
            let name = $(this).text()
            $.ajax({
                url: '/recommendations/add-product',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'recommendationId': {{ recommendations.id }},
                    'productId': productId
                },
                dataType: 'JSON',
                complete : function (response) {
                    $.toast({
                        heading: 'Produit ajouté avec succès',
                        text: 'Ajout de ' + name,
                        position: 'bottom-right',
                        loaderBg: '#ff6849',
                        icon: 'success',
                        hideAfter: 3000,
                        stack: 6
                    });
                    let nameProduct = response.responseJSON['name_product']
                    let input = '<li><b>'+ nameProduct +'</b> <small>0.75 L/ha</small></li>'
                    $('#products_list').append( input )
                }
            })
        })
```

I send two id to my controller

On my controller i want transform this ID (String) to Entity for put  this to relational db

```
/**
     * @Route("recommendations/add-product", name="recommendations.add.product")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function canevasAddProduct( Request $request )
    {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            //-- SETTERS
            $recommendationProducts = new RecommendationProducts();
            $recommendationProducts->setProduct( $request->get('productId') );
            $recommendationProducts->setRecommendation( $request->get( 'recommendationId') );

            //-- Go to db new entry
            $this->em->persist($recommendationProducts);
            $this->em->flush();

            return $this->json([
                'name_product' => $recommendationProducts->getProduct()->getName()
            ], 200);
        }

        return new JsonResponse([
            'message' => 'AJAX Only',
            'type' => 'error'
        ]);
    }
```

I use $request->get() but he return a string and not an object of entity.
I use @ParamsConverter but is dont working.

Thank a lot

Comment: Can you show how you tried to use ParamConverter?

Comment: @ParamConverter("productsId", class="Products:class") and after on my controller to get Object $request->attributes->get('productsId')

Comment: In your code it's `productId`, not `productsId`. Did you remember to use both those classes?

Comment: Yeah this is mistake but i have this error Unknown Entity namespace alias 'Products'.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#usage), you're not supposed to give it the class. Take a look at how the entity is defined.

Comment: I add @ParamConverter("products") and on my function public function canevasAddProduct( Products $products Request $request ) and var $products to get my object but i have this Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "products".

Comment: If you're having trouble with the ParamConverter, you can always explicitly fetch those entities from their repositories by using the ids from the request.

Comment: Yeah it's an reply but i want use ParamConverter to learn it

Answer (score 1):

@ParamsConverter can't work with POST value obligation to use GET value

Answer (score 0):

[ParamConverter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) allow to call a converter to convert an id (or other field as slug, name, etc...) to an Entity

For me, to use this functionality, you should update your code as follow (Change entity name in function param if I'm wrong with entity class name), I try with my own code and entity, and this give me the correct entity for given id in url, so this should work for symfony side, i'm not sure for Ajax call

```
/**
 * @Route("recommendations/add-product/{productId}/{recommandationId}", name="recommendations.add.product",
 *     requirements={"productId": "\d+", "recommandationId": "\d+"})
 * @Entity("product", expr="repository.find(productId)")
 * @Entity("recommandation", expr="repository.find(recommandationId)")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function canevasAddProduct( Request $request, Product $product, Recommandation $recommandation )
{
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        //-- SETTERS
        $recommendationProducts = new RecommendationProducts();
        $recommendationProducts->setProduct( $product );
        $recommendationProducts->setRecommendation( $recommandation );

        //-- Go to db new entry
        $this->em->persist($recommendationProducts);
        $this->em->flush();

        return $this->json([
            'name_product' => $recommendationProducts->getProduct()->getName()
        ], 200);
    }

    return new JsonResponse([
        'message' => 'AJAX Only',
        'type' => 'error'
    ]);
}
```

And update Ajax Call to put id in url and not in data

```
$(".isProduct").click(function (e) {
    let productId = $(this).attr('product_id')
    let name = $(this).text()
    $.ajax({
        url: '/recommendations/add-product/'+productId+'/'+{{ recommendations.id }},
        type: 'POST',
        complete : function (response) {
            $.toast({
                heading: 'Produit ajouté avec succès',
                text: 'Ajout de ' + name,
                position: 'bottom-right',
                loaderBg: '#ff6849',
                icon: 'success',
                hideAfter: 3000,
                stack: 6
            });
            let nameProduct = response.responseJSON['name_product']
            let input = '<li><b>'+ nameProduct +'</b> <small>0.75 L/ha</small></li>'
            $('#products_list').append( input )
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thx yes @ParamsConverter can't work with POST value obligation to use GET value

Answer (score -2):

To get post data, you can use

```
json_decode($request->getContent());
```

Comment: How is this in any way connected to turning an identifier into an entity?

Comment: Get POST information it's not a problem it's to turn an id to entity

Comment: You can find here many methods how to use paramconveter   https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html